# Filter based on percentage of samples with an observation in DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table of data with multiple samples. For each sample there are multiple observations. Not all samples share the same observations. I want to filter this table to remove observations that have a value > x and are observed in > y % of samples.

For example I have samples with observations. I want to filter out observations with a score > 5 but only if the observation occurs in > 75% of the samples.

```
Sample  Month   Day score
A   1   1   8
A   2   2   3
A   5   3   9
B   1   1   8
B   2   2   3
B   5   3   9
C   1   1   8
C   2   4   2
C   2   5   20
D   1   1   8
D   2   5   20
D   5   6   9
```

So here only the observation on Month 1 and Day 1 would be removed as it occurs in all the samples with a score > 8. No other observation is across > 75% of samples.

I would like to be able to do this filtering using DPLYR. I know I can group_by Month and Day and filter() observations with a score less than or equal to 8 but how do I combine that with only including rows where that observation occurs in only a percentage of the samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could do the following:

```
n_samples  <- n_distinct(df$Sample) # total number of samples
df %>% 
  group_by(score, Month, Day) %>% 
  filter(!((n_distinct(Sample)/n_samples > 0.75) & (score > 5)))
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
# # Groups:   score, Month, Day [5]
#    Sample Month   Day score
#   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1      A     2     2     3
# 2      A     5     3     9
# 3      B     2     2     3
# 4      B     5     3     9
# 5      C     2     4     2
# 6      C     2     5    20
# 7      D     2     5    20
# 8      D     5     6     9
```